# Improving Query/View Load-Time [Ruby on Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, optimization, view

I'm experiencing some pretty slow load times with one of the pages of my Rails app. I have made some headway in my attempts to improve performance, but not as much as I had hoped. I'm wondering if I'm doing something silly to cause myself this grief or if anyone could offer me advice to better optimize my models/migrations/queries/views. I'm running Rails 3.1 and using PostgreSQL. This is what I've tried so far:

- added includes(:items => :category) to the controller's query, as an attempt to fetch all the ItemCategories in advance, rather than running additional queries when outfits_helper requires them.
- rendering partials as collections, rather than iterating through arrays/relations manually
- added indexes to tables that are being accessed by the problematic controller action / view

  - outfits table: indexes for user_id and category_id
  - items table: indexes for user_id and category_id
  - outfit_items table: indexes for item_id, outfit_id, and [outfit_id, item_id]

Below are the relevant parts of my code:

## Controller

```
# outfits_controller.rb

NUM_OUTFITS_PER_PAGE = 8

def other_users_outfits
  # using Kaminari for pagination
  @outfits = Outfit.does_not_belong_to_user(current_user).in_category_with_id(category_id).includes(:items => :category).page(params[:page]).per(NUM_OUTFITS_PER_PAGE)
end
```

## Models

```
# outfit.rb

has_many :items, :through => :outfit_items
belongs_to :category, :class_name => 'OutfitCategory'

scope :does_not_belong_to_user, proc {|user| where('user_id != ?', user.id) }

scope :in_category_with_id, proc {|cat_id|
  if cat_id.blank?
    scoped
  else
    where(:category_id => cat_id)
  end
}
```

.

```
# outfit_item.rb

belongs_to :item
belongs_to :outfit
```

.

```
# item.rb

has_many :outfit_items
has_many :outfits, :through => :outfit_items
belongs_to :category, :class_name => 'ItemCategory'
```

.

```
# item_category.rb

has_many :items, :foreign_key => 'category_id'
```

.

```
outfit_category.rb

has_many :outfits, :foreign_key => 'outfit_id'
```

## Migrations

```
# create_outfits.rb

def self.up
  create_table :outfits do |t|
    t.column :category_id, :integer
    t.column :user_id, :integer
    t.timestamps
  end

  add_index :outfits, :category_id
  add_index :outfits, :user_id
end
```

.

```
# create_outfit_items.rb

def self.up
  create_table :outfit_items, :id => false do |t|
    t.column :item_id, :integer
    t.column :outfit_id, :integer
    t.timestamps
  end

  add_index :outfit_items, :item_id
  add_index :outfit_items, :outfit_id
  add_index :outfit_items, [:outfit_id, :item_id]   
end
```

.

```
# create_items.rb

def self.up
  create_table :items do |t|
    t.column :category_id, :integer
    t.column :user_id, :integer
    t.timestamps
  end

  add_index :items, :category_id
  add_index :items, :user_id
end
```

.

```
# create_item_categories.rb
def self.up
  create_table :item_categories do |t|
    t.column :name, :string
    t.column :category_type, :string
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

.

```
# create_outfit_categories.rb

def self.up
  create_table :outfit_categories do |t|
    t.column :name, :string, :limit => 100, :null => false
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

## Views

```
# other_users_outfits.html.haml

= render :partial => 'other_users_outfit', :collection => outfits, :as => :outfit
```

.

```
# _other_users_outfit.html.haml

.outfit
  .primary-items
    = render :partial => 'other_users_outfit_primary_item', :collection => primary_outfit_items_top_to_bottom(outfit), :as => :item
  .secondary-items
    = render :partial => 'other_users_outfit_secondary_item', :collection => secondary_outfit_items(outfit), :as => :item
```

.

```
# _other_users_outfit_primary_item.html.haml

= image_tag item.image_url(:outfit_item), :class => 'primary-outfit-item'
```

.

```
# _other_users_outfit_secondary_item.html.haml

= image_tag item.image_url(:baby_thumb), :class => 'secondary-outfit-item'
```

## Helper

```
# outfits_helper.rb

def primary_outfit_items_top_to_bottom(outfit)
  primary_items = []
  primary_items.push(outfit_item_in_category(outfit, 'Tops'))
  primary_items.push(outfit_item_in_category(outfit, 'Full-lengths'))
  primary_items.push(outfit_item_in_category(outfit, 'Bottoms'))
  primary_items.push(outfit_item_in_category(outfit, 'Footwear'))
  primary_items.compact
end

def secondary_outfit_items(outfit)
  outfit.items.select{|item| item.category.category_type == 'secondary' }
end

def outfit_item_in_category(outfit, cat_name)
  outfit.items.select{|item| item.category.name == cat_name }.first
end
```

## Console Output

```
User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT DISTINCT users.id, users.* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
(0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT 1 AS count_column FROM "outfits" WHERE (user_id != 3) LIMIT 8 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count 

Outfit Load (0.7ms)  SELECT DISTINCT outfits.id, outfits.* FROM "outfits" WHERE (user_id != 3) ORDER BY outfits.created_at DESC LIMIT 8 OFFSET 0

OutfitItem Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "outfit_items".* FROM "outfit_items" WHERE "outfit_items"."outfit_id" IN (28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21)

Item Load (2.2ms)  SELECT DISTINCT items.id, items.*, "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."id" IN (18, 20, 23, 7, 6, 30, 4, 1, 17, 5, 15, 12, 9, 29, 10, 19, 3, 8, 13) ORDER BY items.created_at DESC

ItemCategory Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "item_categories".* FROM "item_categories" WHERE "item_categories"."id" IN (4, 6, 2, 1, 3, 7)

Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_secondary_item.html.haml (1.2ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_secondary_item.html.haml (0.1ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_primary_item.html.haml (2.8ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_secondary_item.html.haml (1.4ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_secondary_item.html.haml (0.9ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_primary_item.html.haml (1.2ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_secondary_item.html.haml (0.3ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_secondary_item.html.haml (0.9ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_primary_item.html.haml (2.7ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_secondary_item.html.haml (0.8ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_secondary_item.html.haml (0.7ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_primary_item.html.haml (1.2ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_secondary_item.html.haml (1.1ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_secondary_item.html.haml (0.3ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_primary_item.html.haml (2.2ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_secondary_item.html.haml (0.8ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_secondary_item.html.haml (0.3ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_primary_item.html.haml (3.4ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_secondary_item.html.haml (0.3ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_secondary_item.html.haml (0.0ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_primary_item.html.haml (2.6ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_secondary_item.html.haml (0.3ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_secondary_item.html.haml (0.3ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit_primary_item.html.haml (2.1ms)
Rendered outfits/_other_users_outfit.html.haml (56.3ms)
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "outfits" WHERE (user_id != 3)
Rendered outfits/other_users.html.haml within layouts/application (2073.5ms)

Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."name" = 'admin' LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles"."id" = "roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "roles_users"."user_id" = 3 AND "roles"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1

Rendered layouts/_top_nav.html.haml (1.0ms)
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "items" WHERE "items"."user_id" = 3

Rendered layouts/_points_display.html.haml (5.7ms)

Outfit Load (0.6ms)  SELECT DISTINCT outfits.id, outfits.* FROM "outfits" WHERE "outfits"."user_id" = 3 ORDER BY outfits.created_at DESC

OutfitCategory Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "outfit_categories".* FROM "outfit_categories"
```

.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is it in production or development environment?

Comment: It's worse in production, but still noticeably slower than all the other views in development.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see that could stand improvement is the code in the helper. Is there a reason why you're doing this:

```
def outfit_item_in_category(outfit, cat_name)
  outfit.items.select{|item| item.category.name == cat_name }.first
end
```

instead of pushing this code to a scope in the Item model? If you have a lot of items, you're basically doing a SELECT * on them and then filtering in Ruby.

Comment: The reason I'm using that helper method, as opposed to using a scope in the Item model, is because 1) I do actually need all the Items in the view and 2) because of the somewhat arbitrary nature of the sorting "algorithm", I don't believe I could handle it within a model scope, unless I added a column whose sole purpose would be to provide a means to sort Items for this particular view.